# send an email after veryfy the email in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, email

I am working with laravel 5.7 and has designed a verify system in controller like this,

```
 public function verifyUser($token)
    {
        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();
        if(isset($verifyUser) ){
            $user = $verifyUser->user;
            if(!$user->verified) {
                $verifyUser->user->verified = 1;

                $verifyUser->user->save();

                $info = "Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.";
            }else{
                $info = "Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.";
            }
        }else{
             return redirect()->back()->with('warning', "Sorry your email cannot be identified.");
        }

         return redirect()->back()->with('info', $info);
    }
}
```

now i need send a default email to admin `admin@mybook.net` to notify after veryfied above system inside this methods. how can I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write your code like this:

```
public function verifyUser($token)
{
    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();
    if(!$verifyUser) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('warning', "Sorry your email cannot be identified.");
    }

    $user = $verifyUser->user;
    if($verifyUser->user->verified) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Your e-mail is already verified. You can now login.');
    }
    $verifyUser->user->update(['verified' => 1]);
    // Send email here.
    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Your e-mail is verified. You can now login.');
}
```